# Why does "meta-" translate to “元-”?

Tags: translation, etymology, loanwords

Why does "meta-" translate to “元-”?

For example, metadata=元数据, meta-analysis=元分析, metaphysics=元物理学。

I understand meta-X to mean "X that is about/of/concerning X". But 元 tends to mean "basic/original/fundamental". Why have people used it for "meta-"?

Answer (score 3):

**A basic meaning of "元" is "primary/first"**.

**"metadata"** - a set of **(existing/primary)** data that describes and gives information about other data.

**"meta-analysis"** - "examination of data from a number of **(existing/primary)** independent studies of the same subject, in order to determine overall trends.
"

**"metaphysics"** - the branch of philosophy that deals with the **first(元)** principles of things, including abstract concepts such as being, knowing, substance, cause, identity, time, and space"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, `meta` comes from here:  the `meta-programming` is translated as `元编程`.

p.s. as a chinese software developer, I also can't understand why meta = 元. Also including these tranlation:

- socket: 嵌套字
- stack: 堆栈
- private key: 私钥
- Hash: 哈希

The Chinese translation from English is full of bullshit. So we in most cases we speak English word instead of Chinese.

[image]